# Change y-axis (horizontal) scrollbar styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I want to change the horizontal scrollbar styles of a div.

I successfully changed the x-axis (vertical) scrollbar style but when I added y-axis scroll, it is taking same styles as I added for the y-axis.

I want to style both scrollbars differently. Is there any possible way to make this happen?

Current CSS for (x-axis) vertical scrollbar:

```
 .list-group {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height:  335px;
    border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    padding: 10px;
}
.list-group::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:35px;
}
.list-group::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment {
    background-image: url('../images/arrow down.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}


.list-group::-webkit-scrollbar-button:decrement {
    background-image: url('../images/arrow up.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of what you have so far?

Comment: @freginold I need horizontal and vertical scroll bars, both on the same div. But different styles for both scrollbars. I hope this can clear thing what I need. I styled the y-axis scrollbar using the CSS above, but when I added x-axis scroll to the same div it is taking same styles which I added for the y-axis.

Comment: Ah okay, much clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by simple apply `overflow-y:scroll` on that div.
I hope this will help you.

```css
div
{
 width: 30em;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #00bd86;
  outline: 2px solid slategrey;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
  Its a test div
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to change the style for the horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: I also change the style of horizontal scroll bar.can you explain this more?? @freginold

Comment: There is no horizontal scroll bar in your example.

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid Actually I need horizontal and vertical scroll bars, both on the same div. But different styles for both scrollbars. I hope this can clear thing what I need.

Comment: @Samlano i hope this link will help you. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/aqqn6csn/2/)

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid It may look different in other browsers, but both scroll bars are styled the same in IE11.

Comment: Looks good on Android browser though. Maybe just needs the `-ms-` prefixing for IE.

Comment: @AsifSharifShahid Bhai! Hilarious. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help. **Marked as the answer**

Comment: I am somehow unable to use the psuedo styles. i.e. apply :horizontal or :vertical to scrollbars. Is there anything I need to import to do so.

Comment: Its css psuedo classes, you don't need any library. Can you share piece of code for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

They this code:

```
#container::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {
    background-color: red;
}
    
#container::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-color: green;
}
    
#container::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment {
    background-color: yellow;
}
    
#container::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement {
    background-color: blue;
}
```